# Partice Hair Stands Straight up

Tags: particles, hair

I have styled the hair on a character.  After closing the file then opening it again, the hair stands straight up in object mode.  When I go into particle edit mode, however, it retains the style I gave it.  I am using version 2.81.  What would be the cause of this?

Comment: Also, when I enable hair physics it goes back to the correct style.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried applying the object's location and it fixed the problem.